# Why empty directory is not being shown in Git Bash (Linux)?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am working on a computer which is running Windows 7 64-bit. I have installed Git and am working on Git Bash.

On my D: drive I have a directory named `Temp5`.

Inside `Temp5` directory I have a directory named `EmptyDir_5_1` and nothing else.

Inside `EmptyDir_5_1` directory I have a directory named `EmptyDir_5_1_1` and nothing else.

Inside `EmptyDir_5_1_1` directory there is nothing.

I opened Git Bash and changed directories to the `Temp5` directory using this command:

```
cd /d/Temp5
```

Now I want to see all the contents, including subdirectory contents, as single items per line. So I used this command:

```
ls -1 *
```

But it is only displaying this output:

> EmptyDir_5_1_1

I was expecting it to display the EmptyDir_5_1 directory as well, and the fact that the EmptyDir_5_1_1 is a sub-directory of the EmptyDir_5_1 directory. Instead, it just skips displaying the EmptyDir_5_1 directory. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to see all the contents including subdirectory contents, single item per line.

To get the output you want use the `-R` (list subdirectories recursively) option:

```
$ ls -R *
EmptyDir_5_1:
EmptyDir_5_1_1

EmptyDir_5_1/EmptyDir_5_1_1:
```

If you want the `-l` (longlisting format):

```
$ ls -lR *
EmptyDir_5_1:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 DavidPostill None 0 Jul 24 17:04 EmptyDir_5_1_1

EmptyDir_5_1/EmptyDir_5_1_1:
total 0
```

---

#### Explanation

- The wildcard `*` matches the only file in the directory (which is the subdirectory `EmptyDir_5_1`) and `ls` is displaying the contents of that subdirectory.
- Use `echo *` to see exactly what the `*` matches:

```
$ echo *
EmptyDir_5_1
```

- The following commands will give you exactly the same output:

```
$ ls *
EmptyDir_5_1_1

$ ls EmptyDir_5_1
EmptyDir_5_1_1
```

---

#### Further reading

- [ls](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) - List information about files.
- [shell expansions](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-expand.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was using -1 because I was told that -1 means "List 1 item per line" in Git Bash here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457305/Basic-Git-Command-Line-Reference-for-Windows-Users

Comment: You're right. I will update the answer. You can `ls -R *` to get the output you want?

Comment: @srh In your case, with only single subdirectories in `Temp5`, both `ls -1 -R *` and `ls -R *` give identical output.